# Custom Query: Multiple CPTs and a taxonomy filter

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts, tax-query

I want to create a post feed that displays the following:

- ALL posts in the CPT **'custom_post_type_1'**
- Any '**post**'s in the category '**speakers**'

So far, I have this filter which displays all posts in 'custom_post_type_1' and all posts in 'post".

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', ['post', 'custom_post_type_1'] );
} );
```

I suspect I need to do a taxonomy array to accomplish my goal but am having difficulty writing one which filters only 'post' and which also shows all of 'custom_post_type_1' regardless of taxonomy.

I am fairly new to this and appreciate any assistance. (I am using Elementor, hence the mention of elementor in the query.)

Comment: The key question is: does your CPT have the speakers taxonomy as well? In that case, you can't use only `pre_get_posts`. You could leave the filter as is, and then in your template, filter the posts further inside the loop. `if (get_post_type() === 'post' && !has_term('', 'speakers')) continue`

Comment: No, the CPT does not currently have the 'speakers' taxonomy as well. (I could set it up if it made sense). Currently I am having difficulties filtering the posts inside of the loop—I think that's an Elementor limitation.